# mapFragment is null I do not know how to fix this. I have spent hours looking in the internet

Tags: android

mapFragment is null I do not know how to fix this. I have spent hours looking in the internet

```
{
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

               return view;
    //it says java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
}
```

Comment: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;

Comment: the mapFragment is null because no exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're making a Map application ...

Have you declared the fragment with ID "map" in your view layout?

```
<Relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 ... your view layout ...

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Answer (score 0):

i also faced this problem

check in your manifest if you are using this or not

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> <!-- this -->

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsMarkerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

for more information check this link : [google map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker)